# maven-jetty-plugin jetty:run error

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I downloaded a maven project I want to check. When I try to do a mvn jetty:run, there's a warning in the output.

```
[INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.22 ...
2012-03-14 15:26:21.236:INFO::jetty-6.1.22
2012-03-14 15:26:21.334:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@4df93ace{/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase,E:\%rainbow\source\struts2-jquery\struts2-jquery-grid-showcase\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:189)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:65)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:55)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:945)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:651)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:188)
at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:204)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:221)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configure(AbstractConfiguration.java:113)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configureWebApp(AbstractConfiguration.java:96)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration.configureWebApp(Configuration.java:149)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2012-03-14 15:26:21.359:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9999
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 10 seconds.
```

I have no idea what is wrong. I've tried the following things:

-Cleaning the project
-Change the value for my classpath
-Cleaning the local repository
-Use a different version of jetty

What could be wrong with my configuration?

EDIT: Adding the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="struts2-jquery-showcase" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Test App</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I did `mvn jetty:run` in 2 different projects, but I got the same error. Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like there might be a bad URL somewhere in your web.xml.  can you post your web.xml?

Comment: at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:204)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:221)

That indicates it is an issue in parsing the web.xml for the webapp you are deploying.

Comment: uhh. there is a closing <web-app> tag in your web.xml right?

Comment: If this is a copy&past of your web.xml you missed the end-tag </web-app> at the end of the file. Otherwise there is something else wrong.

Comment: Yes, both web.xml have the ending tag.  I realize what was my mistake. It is because of the name of the directory. It includes a "%" character. I removed this and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

> I realize what was my mistake. It is because of the name of the directory. It includes a "%" character. I removed this and everything works